# How do I add CA certificate in fiddler requests or Postman requests?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, postman, fiddler, azure-api-management

I have created a couple of `API's` and now I have to test them using `Fiddler` or any certificate friendly tools. The `requests` which are not having **valid certificate** must be rejected by the server.

**Certificate Background**

Here are the two certificate's issues by `CA`

1. I have one `intermediate` public certificate entitled as
   `MyIntermediate.cer`
2. I have a private certificate for each device which will request my `API` to fetch data.

I have uploaded public certificate - `MyIntermediate.cer` to server [Azure APIM]

[image]

Now to test the `API's`, I have to use some tools like `Fiddler` or `Postman` or any other tool which supports certificate upload/reading from store

I do not see any options in these tools to upload or read from windows store. Here I need help

I see settings in postman but it seems like not for `CA` certificates because I do not have `key` file.

[image]

**APIM Details**

Azure API manager is the service provided by Microsoft. All the request will be processed by APIM. I have uploaded `MyIntermediate.cer` public certificate to APIM. So, to call `GetCustomer` someone has to have certificate which is trusted by `MyIntermediate.cer`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to have "private certificate for each device" along with it's password (if it was saved with one) to make an authenticated call. If you want to rely on APIM's ability to validate certificate chain then you'll indeed need to upload intermediate certificate, and possible root certificate as well if it's not one of the public ones.

Comment: I do have "private certificate for each device" but question is, how do we test it using postman or Fiddler?

Comment: Fiddler and Postman both use the Windows Certificate Store (`certlm.msc` or `certmgr,.msc`).